# How do I add environment variables to launch.json in VSCode for a rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am using ruby-debug-ide and debase for debugging in vs code in that when i start debugging by default server is started in development environment, how to debug in a different environment like test/qa? how to configure this launch.json

My launch.json file

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Rails server",
        "type": "Ruby",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/rails",
        "args": [
            "server"
        ],
        "showDebuggerOutput": true,
        "env": {
            "PATH": "/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@codeforkout/bin:/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@global/bin:/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin:/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin",
            "GEM_HOME": "/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@codeforkout",
            "GEM_PATH": "/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@codeforkout:/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@global",
            "RUBY_VERSION": "ruby-2.6.3"
        }
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For time being i changed the default environment to qa by adding the below line in boot.rb, so now whenever i run `rails s` qa environment is booted by default

`ENV["RACK_ENV"] =  "qa"`

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add `-e test` to the `rails server` command:

```
{
    ...

    "args": [
        "server -e test"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Lukas, Below exception is thrown when i try to execute it.  
`d to "[]".
rails aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'rails server -e qa' (See the list of available tasks with `rails --tasks`)
/Users/giri.shankar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@codeforkout/gems/railties-5.2.5/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'`

Comment: @Giri can you post your launch.json file?

Comment: added my launch.json in the question.

Comment: Oh i'm sorry my fault. You only have to put `server -e test`